# Why does exception still get thrown after catch in async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async-await

When an exception is caught, the rest of the code still execute.

```
function bad(){
    //throw new Error('I am an exception')
    return Promise.reject("I am an exception")
}

(
 async function (){
      let  msg = await bad().catch( e=>console.log("This is an error: " + e))
      console.log("I want to stop before executing this line ")
 }
)()
```

I'm trying to catch the exception in this way instead of try and catch

My first issue is how to stop the code from reaching the rest of the code after the error is caught.

The second issue is, if I replaced the Promise reject with the commented out throw error, the exception error thrown won't be caught, why is that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're converting rejection to fulfillment with your `catch` handler. The `await` will await the promise returned by `catch`, which never rejects. So there's no reason the code wouldn't continue, since `await` only sees a fulfilled (never rejected) promise.

Remember that `catch` returns a new promise that will settle based on what the rejection handler does. Your rejection handler suppresses the error by effectively returning `undefined`, thus fulfilling the promise.

It's very much as though you did this:

```
async function (){
    let msg;
    try {
        msg = await bad();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("This is an error: " + e);
    }
    console.log("I want to stop before executing this line ")
}
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> So there is no way other than including all my code inside the try block, and only use the one-liner `.catch()` if I have no more code to follow ?

Just to get it out of the way: Usually, the best thing is not to handle errors at all in any function other than the top-level entry point to the code (e.g., functions called at the top level of your code or by event handlers). Handling errors too soon is a classic antipattern. Allow them to propagate to the caller where they can be handled in a centralized fashion.

But in situations where it's appropriate to handle the error at this level, yes, `try`/`catch` is probably your best bet with your following logic in the `try` block:

```
async function() {
     try {
         let msg = await bad();
         console.log("I want to stop before executing this line ")
     } catch (e) {
         console.log("This is an error: " + e);
     }
}
```

It also has the advantage of not having a variable declared in the containing scope that you're not going to use. If the "one liner" thing is important to you, there's no much difference at all between the `.catch` and the `catch`:

```
async function() {
     try {
         let msg = await bad();
         console.log("I want to stop before executing this line ")
     } catch (e) { console.log("This is an error: " + e); }
}
```

Or you could return a flag value of some kind:

```
async function() {
     let msg = await bad().catch(e => { console.log("This is an error: " + e); return null; });
     if (msg === null) {
         return;
     }
     console.log("I want to stop before executing this line ")
}
```

But frankly, that's really swimming against the current. :-)

Comment: So there is no way other than including all my code inside the try block, and only use the one-liner .catch() if I have no more code to follow ?

Comment: Also what doesn't the (throw) get caught by the catch clause ?

Comment: @YoussefMohamed - I've updated the answer to address your first comment. I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking in your second one.

Comment: I meant "why" but couldn't edit the comment .. my question was, why if I changed the `Promise.reject` to the commented out `throw new Error` the catch wouldn't catch it and the exception would still be thrown ?

Comment: @YoussefMohamed - You mean `function bad(){ throw new Error('I am an exception'); }`? Because `bad` isn't an `async` function, so it's a synchronous error thrown by calling `bad`, which causes the `async` function you're calling it from to reject its promise. It doesn't go to the `catch` because the `bad()` is terminated by the error. (Even if it weren't, it wouldn't return a promise.) If `bad` were an `async` function, that `throw` would indeed get caught by the `.catch` handler.

Comment: (Just a side note: I go into promises in depth in Chapter 8 of my new book, and `async`/`await` in Chapter 9. Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: Ok great, but one final thing, even if I didn't use async/await at all, the thrown exception wouldn't still be caught by my original catch clause.

Comment: @YoussefMohamed - Right, that's the same situation as above -- the `bad()` part throws a synchronous exception, so it doesn't return a promise, so there's no promise to call the `.catch` method on, so... :-)

Comment: Just to add on a bit: It's useful to remember that `.then`/`.catch` isn't special syntax, they're just method calls on an object returned by a function that returns a promise. In contrast, within an `async` function, the behavior of `try`/`catch`, `throw`, and even loops (if there's an `await` in the loop) are altered to support asynchronous execution.